# How do I correctly include copyright statements for included libraries?

Tags: licensing, gpl, mit-license

How do I correctly include copyright statements for included libraries?

I have a program that uses libraries which are licensed under the GPL and MIT (either jointly under both, just only MIT) licences.

How do I specify this at the top of a combined and minified file?

I have this currently:

```
My Program (GPL)
Copyright 2009-2013, Me

jQuery (GPL/MIT)
Copyright 2005, 2012 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors

Some other library (MIT)
Copyright 2013, Some other person

This file is part of My Program.

My Program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

My Program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with My Program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

...jQuery's code...
...my code...
...some other libraries code...
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention all the copyright holders, that's all that's needed. The overall code must be under GPL, so you don't even need to mention that parts were originally under MIT; only files that are completely MIT-licensed should retain MIT license header.